# Using linked duplicates does not reduce poly count

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to optimize my scene, in terms of memory.
I figured I could use *linked duplicates* for things like chairs and tables that are the exact replicas.

But I when I turn on scene stats on display, I see face count still go up even after duplicating linked, it is like I duplicated it the typical standard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facecount of *linked duplicates* only concerns *base mesh* faces.
If a linked duplicate has modifiers (like *Subdivision surface*), the facecount still goes up.

To keep facecount down even with modifiers, use *Collection Instances* instead.

[image]